# Where can i get good resources to start learning the zikula framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, zikula

A client just asked me to develop a site for her company and she particular requests the use to of the Zikula PHP framework.

I don't want to propose something different cause i think i can pull it off. I have two major concerns.

- How can i build templates on Zikula?
- How can i customize it?

I will be more than happy i could get links to where i could read about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zikula is the [new name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostNuke) for PostNuke. There's a plethora of resources out there for postnuke development. A quick search should find plenty of material to help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

The [home page](http://zikula.org/)?

Comment: I want some blog post from somebody other than Zikula.

Comment: you should mention that in your question then :)